# Deploy Django App using AWS Elasticstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Django Project on AWS using Elastic Beanstalks. I am following this Link for deployment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html.

Folder Structure:

```
Project
├── logs.txt
├── requirements.txt
└── project
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── miscellaneousConfig
    ├── README.md
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── img
    │   ├── js
    ├── abc1
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── file1.html
    │   │   └── file2.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── abc
        ├── functions.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        ├── views.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

File: .ebextensions/01-project.config[Updated]:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "abc.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "./project:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "project/abc/wsgi.py"
```

File: .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: project-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: project
  default_ec2_keyname: project_ec2_key
  default_platform: Python 3.4
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: null
```

File wsgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "abc.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Commands:

1) 'eb create'

INFO: Successfully launched environment:

2) eb open

Internal Server Error (on browser)

Logs:(By running: eb logs > logs.txt)

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0] ImportError: No module named 'abc'
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0] mod_wsgi (pid=2857): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/project/abc/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0] mod_wsgi (pid=2857): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/project/abc/wsgi.py'.
[remote xx.x.xx.xx:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/project/abc/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]     django.setup()
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]     self._setup(name)
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
[remote xx.xx.xx.xx:0]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
```

Can someone please suggest how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks,

Comment: @Baterson Please provide your input. Stuck on this since 3 days.

Comment: what's your `reqiurements.txt` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this one

```
import os, sys    
sys.path.append('path/to/abc')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "abc.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Change ebextensions/01-project.config:

```
option_settings:
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment": 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "abc.settings" 
PYTHONPATH: "./project:$PYTHONPATH"  
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python": 
WSGIPath: "project/abc/wsgi.py"
```

I think it is better to give the full path as "PYTHONPATH"

Comment: Added following lines to the file: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..' )
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/../project')

Comment: Still no change in output. Is there a need to 'eb deploy' to make the changes getting reflected ? If yes, then I am getting the following error:

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'abc'. 
container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/01-project.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Comment: Can you pls tell how to give the full path for PYTHONPATH variable ? (Currently, the code is residing in my local path)

Comment: `cd` into project folder and run `pwd`, you will get the path

Comment: Changed .project/abc to ./project in ebextensions->config file and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Changed

```
PYTHONPATH: "./project/abc:$PYTHONPATH"
```

to

```
PYTHONPATH: "./project:$PYTHONPATH"
```

in .ebextensions/01-project.config File and it worked. :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `INSTALLED_APPS = "abc"` is present in your settings.py file

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'project',
)

Comment: what's your folder structure? Where is abc?

Comment: Added Folder Structure in the Question.

Comment: Try to add abc to the INSTALLED APPS list

Comment: Changed .project/abc to ./project in ebextensions->config file and it worked. Thanks.